# Rewriting URLS in IIS having +

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following URL - website.com/ABCDETest+PHP, and every time I access the website I get 404 - File or directory not found. My web.config is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="Test" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Does anyone happen to know why I am getting the 404 page and it is not redirecting to the index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be getting HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found

This is not because the rule did not work but because of security related where request filtering module is denying the request.

**The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.**

You have to do following

IIS manager ->Find the Website >Go to the Request Filtering ->Edit Feature Settings and enable setting "Allow double escaping" .

[image: allow double escaping in IIS request filtering module]